# Android SearchView widget custom handlers

Tags: android

How does one add custom handlers to Android's SearchView widget?  Particularly, when the user types (onKeyPress?), or when the user presses the search-enter key (onSubmit?)?

I have read the searchable configuration functionality, but I don't need it. I simply want to use the widget because it already provides all the UI behavior I want. (It conveniently added the search icon on my action bar, and when pressed, it expands into an editable text field where users can type their search words.)

I've added the SearchView widget into my menus.xml file with only one tag, and surprisingly that's all the UI functionality I need.

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

I tried googling for answers, but all I've found on SearchView so far is still about using the searchable configuration.  Please help.

**Added:**

And other handlers too, like when user presses the X button to delete the search word immediately?

Comment: Have you checked SearchViews documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html. When the user types for instance can be caught with setOnQueryTextListener(SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I've read the docs, and I think this is just what I need.  I'm still quite new to android dev, so just to confirm, after inflating the menu then get SearchView instance, I'll attach the handler from there?

Comment: Yes, it works! I created the listener class and got a reference to the SearchView widget and added it by this line `((SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView()).setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);`

Comment: nice! Lesson of the day: read the docs! ;-)

Comment: Yes, thank for the great lesson of today! ^_^